# How to make bullet points bigger in password mode for QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlineedit

I have a `QLineEdit` to which I set the [`echoMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#echoMode-prop) to [`QLineEdit::Password`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum) like this:

```
myLineEdit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
```

The bullets are shown, but they are too small for the purpose of my application:

[image]

I need to make them bigger like this:

[image]

I have tried to increase the font size using a stylesheet like that:

```
myLineEdit->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { font-size: 20px; }");
```

This indeed makes the bullets bigger, but the text gets bigger as well.

How to increase the size of bullet points preserving the size of the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a unicode character that shows a larger circle through `lineedit-password-character`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    auto lay = new QFormLayout(&w);
    QLineEdit *normal_le = new QLineEdit;
    normal_le->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
    normal_le->setText("Pass");
    lay->addRow("Normal: ", normal_le);
    for(int i: {9210, 9679, 9899, 11044}){
        QLineEdit *le = new QLineEdit;
        le->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
        le->setText("Pass");
        le->setStyleSheet(QString("QLineEdit[echoMode=\"2\"]{lineedit-password-character: %1}").arg(i));
        lay->addRow(QString::number(i), le);
    }
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have one more question. This solution works well until I applied it for MacOS. I  used the value 11044, but the circle does not appear in MacOS, instead only strange rectangulars appear. Could you pls tell me which reason could be for this?

Comment: @htmlamateur The problem is the font you are using, if the font does not support unicode then you will generate that problem, solution: use another font.

Comment: I use the same font for windows and Mac, in windows that works but in Mac that does not :(

Comment: @htmlamateur What font am I using?

Comment: Sorry I looked again in Mac I use another font (HelveticaNeue), I am checking whether this font supports unicode

Comment: OK, i have checked. It seems HelveticaNeue does not support Unicode. thank you! Do we have another solution for the problem if the font can not be changed ?

Comment: @htmlamateur No, there is no other solution, use another font :-)